# Is it necessary to derive codecs for nested classes in ZIO json?

Tags: zio-json

Noob question about encoding/decoding:  If I have this:

```scala
  case class Pet(name: String, numLegs: Int)
  case class Person(name: String, age: Int, pets: List[Pet])

  implicit val decoder: JsonDecoder[Person] = DeriveJsonDecoder.gen[Person]
  implicit val encoder: JsonEncoder[Person] = DeriveJsonEncoder.gen[Person]
  println( someJson.fromJson[Person] )
```

I get an error that there's no decoder for Pet.  Do I have to define encoders/decoders for every possible nested object in a top-level class?  I'm thinking .gen is a macro, so shouldn't it dive into Person and figure it out?